Android build on bitbicket using ci/cd
Could you please help me with error?
it is my bibucket-pipelines.yml
image: alvrme/alpine-android:android-34-jdk17

pipelines:
  default:                # pipeline definition for all branches
    - parallel:           # running a set of steps at the same time https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-or-run-parallel-steps/
        - step:           # step to build Android debug application
            name: Android Debug Application
            caches:       # caching speed up subsequent execution https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-dependencies/
              - gradle
            script:
              - touch local.properties
              - ./gradlew assembleDebug
            artifacts:
              - app/build/outputs/** 

You can see an error on screenshot. We use gstreamer in our project for streaming

